# Question about implication in proof that predecessor subgraph is a breadth-first tree

Tags: algorithm-analysis, graph-traversal, check-my-answer

Given the following theorem and definitions from *Introduction to Algorithms* 3rd edition by CLRS:

**Theorem 22.5: (Correctness of breadth-first search**)

Let $G = (V, E)$ be a directed or undirected graph, and suppose that $BFS$ is run on $G$ from a given source vertex $s \in V$. Then, during its execution, $BFS$ discovers every vertex $v \in V$ that is reachable from the source $s$, and upon termination, $v.d = \delta(s, v)$ for all $v \in V$. Moreover, for any vertex $v \neq s$ that is reachable from $s$, one of the shortest paths from $s$ to $v$ is a shortest path from $s$ to $v.\pi$ followed by the edge $(v.\pi, v)$.

$\delta(s,v) \rightarrow \text{length of the shortest path from s to v} \\\ v.d\rightarrow \text{distance assigned to vertex $v$ from $s$ by BFS}\\\ v.\pi\rightarrow \text{predecessor of $v$ in the path from $s$ to $v$ in the BFS}$

For a graph $G = (V, E)$ with source $s$, the **predecessor subgraph** of $G$ is $G_{\pi} = (V_{\pi}, E_{\pi})$, where $V_{\pi} = \{ v \in V : v.\pi \neq NIL\} \cup \{s\}$ and $E_{\pi} = \{ (v.\pi, v) : v \in V_{\pi} - \{s\}\}$

The predecessor subgraph $G_{\pi} = (V_{\pi}, E_{\pi})$ is a **breadth-first tree** if $V_{\pi}$ consists of the vertices reachable from $s$ and, for all $v \in V_{\pi}$, the subgraph $G_{\pi}$ contains a unique simple path from $s$ to $v$ that is also a shortest path from $s$ to $v$ in $G$

I have a question about the following proof:

**Lemma 22.6:**

When applied to a directed or undirected graph $G = (V, E)$, procedure BFS constructs $\pi$ so that the predecessor subgraph $G_{\pi} = (V_{\pi}, E_{\pi})$ is a breadth-first tree.

Line 16 of BFS sets $v.\pi = u$ iff $(u, v) \in E$ and $\delta(s, v) < \infty$ - that is, if $v$ is reachable from $s$- and thus $V_{\pi}$ consists of the vertices in $V$ reachable from $s$. Since $G_{\pi}$ forms a tree, it contains a unique simple path from $s$ to each vertex in $V_{\pi}$. By applying **Theorem 22.5** inductively, we conclude that every such path is a shortest path in $G$.

How does it follow from "Line 16 of BFS sets $v.\pi = u$ iff $(u, v) \in E$ and $\delta(s, v) < \infty$ - that is, if $v$ is reachable from $s$" that "$V_{\pi}$ consists of the vertices in $V$ reachable from $s$"?

**Update:**

I understand it as follows: All the nodes with parents are reachable from $s$. $V_{\pi}$ is defined to contain all the nodes in $V$ with parents. Since we know all nodes that have parents are reachable from $s$, it follows that $V_{\pi}$ consists of the vertices in $V$ reachable from $s$.